# Find values by averaging values of another column

Tags: r

```
   Ozone Solar.R Wind    TempC Month Day
1    41     190  7.4 19.44444     5   1
2    36     118  8.0 22.22222     5   2
3    12     149 12.6 23.33333     5   3
4    18     313 11.5 16.66667     5   4
5    NA      NA 14.3 13.33333     5   5
6    28      NA 14.9 18.88889     5   6
```

How can I find the month with the highest average temperature?

Answer (score 0):

if you think of a client side solution, real time, I think you should use AngularJS for such real-time calculations, otherwise using ur backend language/database.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
names(with(df, which.max(tapply(TempC, Month, FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE))))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Ozone = c(41L, 36L, 12L, 18L, NA, 28L, 41L, 36L, 
12L, 18L, NA, 28L), Solar.R = c(190L, 118L, 149L, 313L, NA, NA, 
190L, 118L, 149L, 313L, NA, NA), Wind = c(7.4, 8, 12.6, 11.5, 
14.3, 14.9, 7.4, 8, 12.6, 11.5, 14.3, 14.9), TempC = c(19.44444, 
22.22222, 23.33333, 16.66667, 13.33333, 18.88889, 19.54444, 22.32222, 
24.33333, 18.66667, 19.33333, 20.88889), Month = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Day = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), .Names = c("Ozone", "Solar.R", 
"Wind", "TempC", "Month", "Day"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```